# when jqgrid reloadGrid fill empty data

Tags: jqgrid

hi  iam use jqgrid reloadGrid with local json. when reload grid is empty or not fill
this demo [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/153/)
this my code

```
function FillGrid() { 

   var objstr =   [{ id: "12", Name: "Name 41", PackageCode: "8443123a", get: 315 },
            { id: "22", Name: "Name 12", PackageCode: "8314423a", get: 585 },
            { id: "32", Name: "Name 12", PackageCode: "8314423a", get: 56485 }
            ]

    var col = Object.keys(objstr).map(function (itm) { return objstr[itm]; });

 //   $("#" + idgrid).setGridParam({ data: col }).trigger("reloadGrid", {  page: 1 });

    $("#jqg1").setGridParam({ data: objstr, datatype: 'local' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you made a typing error in `FillGrid`. The fixed version

```
function FillGrid() { 
   var objstr = [
     { id: "12", Name: "Name 41", PackageCode: "8443123a", get: 315 },
     { id: "22", Name: "Name 12", PackageCode: "8314423a", get: 585 },
     { id: "32", Name: "Name 12", PackageCode: "8314423a", get: 56485 }
   ];

   $("#packages").setGridParam({
     data: objstr,
     datatype: 'local'
   }).trigger('reloadGrid');
 }
```

works. See https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/154/

Comment: please see this demo https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/156/ dont work reload

Comment: @saeed3164: The last demo is buggy too. `data: objstr` should be fixed to `data: objstr.grd1` because `objstr.grd1` is array of items and not `objstr`. See https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/157/